# Arduino to Arduino communication through IR not working

Tags: arduino-uno, arduino-c++

I have an arduino uno, and a romeo that uses an arduino uno chip. I want to communicate between the two boards using TX/RX pins. When I tried the codes I made it doesn't work.
I tried out these codes, but they didn't work:

master uno;

```
`void setup()
{
  pinMode(A0, INPUT);
  pinMode(A1, INPUT);
  Serial.begin(9600);
  pinMode(A2, INPUT);
  pinMode(A3, INPUT);
}

void loop()
{
  if ((analogRead(A0) < 520 && analogRead(A0) > 500) && (analogRead(A1) < 520 && analogRead(A1) > 500)) {
    Serial.println("0x0");
  }
  if (analogRead(A0) > 522) {
    Serial.println("0x1");
  }
  if (analogRead(A0) < 500) {
    Serial.println("0x2");
  }
  if (analogRead(A1) > 522) {
    Serial.println("0x4");
  }
  if (analogRead(A1) < 500) {
    Serial.println("0x3");
  }
  if (analogRead(A2) > 522) {
    Serial.println("0x5");
  }
  if (analogRead(A2) < 500) {
    Serial.println("0x6");
  }
  if (analogRead(A3) > 522) {
    Serial.println("0x7");
  }
  if (analogRead(A3) < 500) {
    Serial.println("0x8");
  }
  if ((analogRead(A2) < 520 && analogRead(A2) > 500) && (analogRead(A3) < 520 && analogRead(A3) > 500)) {
    Serial.println("0x0");
  }
  delay(10);
}`
```

slave uno;

```
`#include <Servo.h>
int E1 = 5;     //M1 Speed Control
int E2 = 6;     //M2 Speed Control
int M1 = 4;    //M1 Direction Control
int M2 = 7;    //M1 Direction Control
Servo servo_0;
Servo servo_1;
int sr1 = 0;
int sr2 = 0;

///For previous Romeo, please use these pins.
//int E1 = 6;     //M1 Speed Control
//int E2 = 9;     //M2 Speed Control
//int M1 = 7;    //M1 Direction Control
//int M2 = 8;    //M1 Direction Control


void stop(void)                    //Stop
{
  digitalWrite(E1,LOW);
  digitalWrite(E2,LOW);
}
void advance(char a,char b)          //Move forward
{
  analogWrite (E1,a);      //PWM Speed Control
  digitalWrite(M1,HIGH);
  analogWrite (E2,b);
  digitalWrite(M2,HIGH);
}
void back_off (char a,char b)          //Move backward
{
  analogWrite (E1,a);
  digitalWrite(M1,LOW);
  analogWrite (E2,b);
  digitalWrite(M2,LOW);
}
void turn_L (char a,char b)             //Turn Left
{
  analogWrite (E1,a);
  digitalWrite(M1,LOW);
  analogWrite (E2,b);
  digitalWrite(M2,HIGH);
}
void turn_R (char a,char b)             //Turn Right
{
  analogWrite (E1,a);
  digitalWrite(M1,HIGH);
  analogWrite (E2,b);
  digitalWrite(M2,LOW);
}
void setup(void)
{
  servo_0.attach(5, 500, 2500);
  servo_1.attach(6, 500, 2500);
  int i;
  for(i=4;i<=7;i  )
    pinMode(i, OUTPUT);
  Serial.begin(19200);      //Set Baud Rate
  Serial.println("Run keyboard control");
}
void loop(void)
{
  servo_0.write(sr1);
  servo_1.write(sr2);
  if(Serial.available()){
    char val = Serial.read();
      switch(val)
      {
      case '0x1':
        advance (255,255);   //move forward in max speed
        break;
      case '0x2':
        back_off (255,255);   //move back in max speed
        break;
      case '0x3'://Turn Left
        turn_L (100,100);
        break;
      case '0x4'://Turn Right
        turn_R (100,100);
        break;
      case '0x0':
        stop(); //stop
        break;
     case '0x5':
        sr1 += 10;
        break;
      case '0x6':
        sr1 -= 10;
        break;
      case '0x7':
        sr2 += 10;
        break;
      case '0x8':
        sr2 -= 10;
        break;
    }
    else stop();
  }
}`
```

I have tinkered with the codes, but nothing works. And also, they are connected through IR transmitter and receiver. the master uno has 2 joysticks. The slave uno has 2 motors, and 2 servos.

Comment: I think my problem is that I am using analog/digital code, not IR code. I will post an IR code that works for people of the future!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made a code that works for the arduino's, but the ir idea is not very good. it is way too hard having to constantly make sure the ir is facing the receiver.